# Paypal email invoice

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, kohana

I have an e-commerce project developed in Kohana2.3.4V, My problem is Paypal invoice e-mail is not showing the product name or description. I also pass the parameters to the SetExpressCheckout function are as follows:

```
METHOD
VERSION
RETURNURL
CANCELURL
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT
L_ITEMCATEGORY
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY
LOGOIMG
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT
```

When customer clicks on the Paypal button, it will redirect to Paypal home page and at that time we can see all information including Product name, Quantity, price etc., but after the payment success Paypal will send an email, which includes purchase details but it is not showing the product name or description. It is really confusing. Please give me a solution if you know one.

Comment: When redirecting to PayPal, you already know what the customer is about to buy. On successful purchase you can send them your own invoice showing what they have just bought. PayPals email is just a confirmation check that a certain amount of money has been withdrawn from the customers account. Not an actual invoice. Paypal might even not know, what the customer is buying, because it's sole purpose is to manage money flow, not the actual product.

Comment: Yes you are  right..but my client is not agreed this, He need the complete details on Paypal email itself. Is there any solution?

Comment: @DainisAbols Normally Paypal must show the purchase details product wise. Need any additional parameter?

Comment: I suggest you contact PayPals support about that.